# Google wave API + ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-wave

- Is there any API for google wave that
  can be integrated with an asp.net
  webform application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's my [port of the Robot API to .NET](http://code.google.com/p/wave-robot-net-client/). It's unclear whether that's what you're after though - what sort of integration are you looking for? What are you trying to do?